# Cannot connect (via http) to IIS app on Azure VM

Tags: http, iis, azure, virtual-machine

I have created a SQL VM on Microsoft Azure and it's been like a walk in the park:

I was able to connect via RDP all the time. I installed an app to IIS and it was working ok.

Now, i wanted to connect from the outside world, but Chrome just gives me the page is not available error.

My DNS name is sqlmilos.cloudapp.net.

I took down windows firewall on windows server.

IIS is bound to port 80.

As I understand I connect to my VM via cloud service which was created at the same time as VM, and it has same dns name: sqlmilos.cloudapp.net

That cloud service has 2 input endpoints (shown in dashboard):

SQL : 23.102.171.184:5986
SQL : 23.102.171.184:63907

That 63907 port is for RDP and it's working, obviously.
I thought maybe I should bind IIS to 5986 port, just for test, but iis says that port is already used.

So, I was hoping that somebody could give me some pointers how to resolve this.

Best regards,

UPDATE:

I just realized that you can add you own endpoints to VM, so I added one for port 80, so now I have 3 ports open: 80, 5986 and 63907,

but I still cannot connect to application.

Comment: Was your setup process similar to [this](http://www.nimbo.com/blog/how-to-setup-an-azure-virtual-machine-as-a-web-server/)?

Comment: Yeah, exactly. Only I used Windows Server 2008 R2 instead of 2012. As I said, I forgot to add an endpoint for port 80 at first, but I added it later.